# R raster: the cropped raster had different color (brigtness) from original one?

Tags: r, qgis, r-raster

I would like to `crop` a multiband raster (4 bands) by spatial polygons (in SpatialPolygonsDataFrame). When I displayed the original and cropped rasters in QGIS, I found that the cropped raster had different colours from the original one. Here is my code:

```
library(raster) 

mosaic_shp <- shapefile("mo_clipper.shp")
mosaic <- brick('orthomosaic.tif')

mosaic_sub <- crop(mosaic, extent(mosaic_shp))

writeRaster(mosaic_sub, 'mosaic_sub.tif', format = "GTiff", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Partial cropped raster and the corresponding part in original raster in QGIS:

[image][image]

I have no idea how to deal with this issue, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is probably happening is that cropping the image changes the image statistics, which are in turn used by `QGIS` for visualization. Try copying/pasting a layer's style to another and see if the visualization matches. Additionally you can use the value tool to see if the pixel values match.

Comment: Check the style that QGIS is using. the pic on the right looks like its only using one band and doing grayscale, but the one on the left is possibly an RGB pseudo colour image which is probably using the first three of your four bands. Check the second one still has four bands.

Answer (score 0):

After comparing the two rasters carefully in QGIS, I have found the answer. The issue is related to `dataType` argument in the `writeRaster` function. So we just need to modify the code like:

```
library(raster) 

mosaic_shp <- shapefile("mo_clipper.shp")
mosaic <- brick('orthomosaic.tif')

mosaic_sub <- crop(mosaic, extent(mosaic_shp))
data_type <- unique(dataType(mosaic)) # get data type from original raster;

writeRaster(mosaic_sub, 'mosaic_sub.tif', format = "GTiff", overwrite = TRUE, 
            datatype = data_type) # set datatype;
```